# What's wrong with my $wpdb query?

Tags: database

I'm just trying to query the first user, but it outputs this error,

**WordPress database error**: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''wp_users' WHERE ID = 1' at line 1]
SELECT * FROM 'wp_users' WHERE ID = 1

And my code,

```
<?php   
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->show_errors();

$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE ID = %d" , $wpdb->users, 1);
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
echo '</pre>';    
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `$wpdb->prepare` the placeholder `%s` is replaced with something between quotes, so, your query becomes:

```
"SELECT * FROM 'wp_users' WHERE ID = 1"
```

but table names in SQL queries must **not** be wrapped in quotes. So, the right way is:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->users} WHERE ID = %d", 1 );
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Note that this may not work because nothing assure that exists an user with the id = 1. (Actually someone discourages to have user with ID = 1 for security reason).

If you want to pick first user is better to use something like:

```
$user = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->users} ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1" );
```

In this way you get first user row, no matter what its ID is.

Comment: Is it "{$wpdb->users}" secure from SQL inyection? get_row() too?

Comment: You need to escape things for SQL injection when they comes from user input, `$wpdb->users` is just a string that comes from WordPress. If you want to enter paranoia mode you can use `"{esc_sql( $wpdb->users )}"`. Also `"{$wpdb->users}"` is the way WordPress uses for internal queries, if it is insecure all WordPress is insecure. Regarding `get_row` is just another `$wpdb` method (see [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Row)) that returns a single row instead of an array of rows. There is no reason that should make it more or less secure than `get_results` @autorun